# XPath: extract attribute value plus inner text of child element

Tags: xpath

Is it possible to use an XPath expression to extract both the value of an attribute and the value of the inner text of a child element?  For example, I want to obtain the value 6 and the six values 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600 from the following XML:

```
<Main>
    <Example dim="6">
        <Example-i>100,200,300,400,500,600</Example-i>
    </Example>
</Main>
```

I can see how to get the value of the `dim=` attribute (e.g. `//Example/@dim`), and the inner text of the `<Example-i>` element (e.g., `//Example-i/text()`), but I cannot figure out a unified XPath expression to extract both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `fn:concat(...)` function like this

```
concat(/Main/Example/@dim,' - ',/Main/Example/Example-i)
```

Or, in a more generalzied way

```
concat(//Example/@dim,' - ',//Example/Example-i)
```

Its output, in both cases, is

```
6 - 100,200,300,400,500,600
```

Comment: This works and delivers a string.  I now realize that the XPath `|` operator is also applicable (e.g. `//Example/@dim | //Example/Example-i`) when a node set is preferable to a stringified result.